# XML android:gravity value referenced as a variable?

Tags: android, xml, gravity

is there any way to set android:gravity="..." value as a variable so I can change it depending on the configuration?

something like

```
android:gravity="@string/gravityValue"
```

/values

```
<string name="gravityValue">left</string>
```

/values-land

```
<string name="gravityValue">right</string>
```

but that doesnt work as gravity values are flags

thanks!

Comment: make different layout xml for each layout and change the gravity in those xml layout files.

Comment: thats what im trying to avoid

Comment: Is there a reason behind avoiding that?

Comment: big xml files, only this changes, so for the sake of maintability

Comment: If that is the case, I recommend handling setting the gravity dynamically since I don't think xml provides this flexibility.

Comment: If you're mainly concerned about RTL, use `start` and `end` for the gravity values.

Comment: that however doesnt work if width is set to match_parent, well it does, but it aligns european strings to left side, and arabic to right, I want all of those be to right side, since im that given UI both european and arabic can occur

Comment: I thought the start/end goes by the system RTL setting, rather than individual strings. You might be better off subclassing your text-view to set the gravity based on a resource string, then.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have my_layout.xml file in which you have view for which you want to change gravity depending on configuration. Use /layout and /layout-land folders not /values and /values-land. In those directories put separate versions of your my_layout.xml. In each set gravity attribute for view as you need.

Comment: I know, but thats what im trying to avoid as only this value changes, its for RTL stuff specifically (port/land was just an example)

Comment: Like @323go said, if your issue is RTL then make use of `start` and `end` for gravity attribute. Otherwise I think it can only be done programmatically.